# How to restore values in one SQL table from values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on SQL Server 2019. I have two tables, one has data about the cities and the sales representatives' visited numbers stored in Col1 to Col6. And another one has all the deleted values from this table. This table has about 5000 rows. I have to restore the deleted Col values from the backup table. For example, if a row has a null value in Col4 but int values in Col5 and Col6, I have to update this row with the Col4 value from the backup table of the corresponding row as identified by the ID value. In the enclosed screenshot, Col3 of Row1, Col5 of Row2, and Col1 of Row 4 will be updated with the corresponding Col values from the backup table while Row 3 will remain unchanged as the last Col is null. I am new to writing complex SQL queries.

So far I came up with this script.

```
UPDATE p
SET 
--p.Col1 = isnull(p.Col1, a.Col1),
--p.Col2 = isnull(p.Col2, a.Col2),
--p.Col3 = isnull(p.Col3, a.Col3),
--p.Col4 = isnull(p.Col4, a.Col4),
--p.Col5 = isnull(p.Col5, a.Col5),
--p.Col6 = isnull(p.Col6, a.Col6)
p.Col4 = a.Col4
FROM Reps p
INNER JOIN
Deleted a
ON p.ID = a.ID 
WHERE 
a.Col4 is not null
AND p.Col4 is null
```

This works when Col4 is null. So, I have to write the same SQL six times, one each for each Col. I thought of using the IsNull function as shown in the commented-out section of the code. When I tried it, only the last col6 is updated but not Col1 to 5!

```
ID  Name          Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4  Col5   Col6
--- ----------------------------- ----------- -----------  
1   Houston        5     200    NULL   85    200    20
2   Dallas         12    45     890    22    NULL   4
3   San Antonio    34    38     222    3     25     NULL
4   Temple         NULL  567    8      90    23     1
```

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text.

Comment: What's SQL Server V18? The latest is SQL Server 2022, which is version 16.

Comment: Step 1) Build a select which pulls the desired data, probably by joining both tables and conditionally selection values from 1 table or the other. 2) Convert it into an `UPDATE FROM` statement using the documentation. Further enhance your question to contain sample data from both tables and your desired results (as formatted text not images). Bonus points, provide the sample data as DDL+DML to make it easy for us to assist.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple joined update, with `SET Col1 = ISNULL(ThisTable.Col1, OtherTable.Col1)` etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated the SqlServer Version to 2018

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A complete example with both tables, sample data, expected results and DDL would help us help you.

Comment: It's version 2019!

Comment: Aside: [Use the inserted and deleted tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) explains how to use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables in DML triggers. You might not want to use those names for your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot is not available. Please share the information in plain text with the question.

If I got you right you want to update col4 from backup table matching by id of cities table if col4 is null and col5 and col6 is integer

```
update table cities set col4=b.col4
from backupCities b where cities.id=b.id and cities.col4 is null and (col5%1)=0 and (col6%1)=0
```

Comment: Kazi, thanks for your input. Please see my update to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To update all the column once please remove `where clause` you used.

```
UPDATE p
SET 
p.Col1 = isnull(p.Col1, a.Col1),
p.Col2 = isnull(p.Col2, a.Col2),
p.Col3 = isnull(p.Col3, a.Col3),
p.Col4 = isnull(p.Col4, a.Col4),
p.Col5 = isnull(p.Col5, a.Col5),
p.Col6 = isnull(p.Col6, a.Col6)    
FROM Reps p
INNER JOIN
Deleted a
ON p.ID = a.ID
```